# How to migrate data from SQL Server to Cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, nosql, database-migration

I have a big amount of data to transfer from SQL Server to Cassandra. I've developed some code to make the data received from the SQL Server compatible with cassandra but I'm having trouble inserting it. Since it is a lot of data, I'm getting this error after a while:

[image]

I am doing this using nodejs. Here is my code:

```
request.on('row', async function (columns) {
    columns.forEach(async function (column) {
        if (column.metadata.colName.toLowerCase() == sqlTimestampCol.toLowerCase()) {
            data.timestamp = column.value;
            data.partitionName = partition_utils.getPartitionNameByDate(column.value);
        } else {
            dataMap[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        }
        if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
        } else {
            result += column.value + " ";
        }
    });
    data.dataMap = dataMap;

    // INSERT CASSANDRA
    var insertString =
        `INSERT INTO ${cassandraKeyspace}.${cassandraTableName}(${cassandraDateColumn}, month_year_index, dataMap) VALUES (?,?,?)`;

    await cassandraConnection.client.execute(insertString, insertParams, { prepare: true })
        .then(async function () {
            console.log(`Inserted data for ${cassandraTableName} successfully`);
        })
        .catch(async function (error) {
            cassandraConnection.client.shutdown();
            logger.error(error);
        });

    result = "";
    data = {}
});

request.on('doneInProc', function (rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
    cassandraConnection.client.shutdown();
});
connection.execSql(request);
```

I am using npm tedious and datastax cassandra driver. I do a simple `select * from table`  and run the code above (in request.on('row')) for every row of the table but it's not working for me. Is there a proper way to do this?

From what I read the error I am receiving is because I am inserting data faster than cassandra can handle it. Also, is only when the SQL query reaches the end that the new data actually is inserted in cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting the amount of in-flight requests requires manual stream back-pressure handling.

The Node.js driver provides utility methods for that:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.6/features/concurrent-api/#using-a-fixed-query-and-a-readable-stream.

For example:

```js
const stream = myRowStream.pipe(transformRowToArrayOfParameters);
const result = await executeConcurrent(client, insertString, stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have a single client sending thousands of queries on the same connection. It isn't so much that Cassandra can't handle the requests, but that single connection between your client and the cluster is a bottleneck.

In your setup, each connection can only handle 2048 concurrent requests. Once you've hit this limit, your app can't send any more requests.

For maximum throughput, you need to scale horizontally so you have multiple app instances all sending queries. For example, if you have 6 app instances then you can send 6 x 2048 concurrent requests to your Cassandra cluster.

As a side note, if this is a one-off migration of your data to Cassandra then I recommend exporting your data to CSV format and use the [**DataStax Bulk Loader**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) (**DSBulk**). It's a free utility that fully open-source that allows you load/unload data to/from an Apache Cassandra cluster, DSE cluster or [Astra](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) database.

For more info on DSBulk, see the following:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading